K8S secret usage in SQLCMD password is always empty
I’m trying to connect to an SQL server using K8S secret for password but no matter what syntax or method I want to use, the password always empty. If I hardcode the password, everything works fine.
I can also print the secret in the POD using this command and it also returns the password stored in secret (so the POD can actually access to the secret):
kubectl exec -it podname -- printenv MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD

I’m trying to run this little healthcheck:
start-sql.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash

    # Start SQL Server in the background
    /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &

    echo "The password being used is: $MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD"
    echo "Waiting for SQL Server to start..."
    for i in {1..120}; do
      /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P "$MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD" -Q "SELECT 1"
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "SQL Server is up and running."
        break
      else
        echo -n "."
        sleep 1
      fi
    done

Here is my init container:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: ${LOWERASSET}
  labels:
    app: ${ASSET}
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: ${LOWERASSET}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ${ASSET}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ${ASSET}
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 10001
      initContainers:
      - name: init-sql
        image: ${IMAGE}
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "200m"
            memory: "2Gi"
          limits:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: "4Gi"
        command: ["/bin/bash", "/mnt/init/start-sql.sh"]
        env:
        - name: MSSQL_PID
          value: Developer
        - name: ACCEPT_EULA
          value: "Y"
        - name: MSSQL_ENABLE_HADR
          value: "1"
        - name: MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED
          value: "1"
        - name: MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sql-server
              key: pwd
        volumeMounts:
        - name: init-script
          mountPath: /mnt/init
        - name: ${LOWERASSET}
          mountPath: /var/opt/mssql
      containers:
      - name: sqlserver
        image: ${IMAGE}
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "200m"
            memory: "2Gi"
          limits:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: "4Gi"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1433
          name: tcpsql
        env:
        - name: MSSQL_PID
          value: Developer
        - name: ACCEPT_EULA
          value: "Y"
        - name: MSSQL_ENABLE_HADR
          value: "1"
        - name: MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED
          value: "1"
        - name: MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sql-server
              key: pwd
        volumeMounts:
        - name: ${LOWERASSET}
          mountPath: /var/opt/mssql
      volumes:
      - name: init-script
        configMap:
          name: sql-init-script
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: ${LOWERASSET}
      labels:
        app: ${ASSET}
        backup: "${BACKUP}"
    spec:
      storageClassName: encrypted-standard
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 8Gi

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ${LOWERASSET}
  labels:
    app: ${ASSET}
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: ${ASSET}
  ports:
  - name: tcpsql
    protocol: TCP
    port: 1433

What is the correct way to use secret in sqlcmd?
